# How to sort certain sections of a dataframe using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that shows when a pump is on by listing consecutive 1s in a column for the amount of seconds it is on. When it is off it turns to 0s. I am wondering if there is a way to iterate through the data and find sections that are bordered by the 0s?

Example of data below:

Time (seconds):
512,
523,
578,
600,
622,
645,
677,
700,
712,
733,
756,
777,
802,
814....

Pump On (1) Pump Off(0): 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0.....

I essentially need to find the difference between the max and min number only when the pump is on. I am at a loss on how to isolate the ones and find the how many cycles have run and for how long.

Comment: Yes.  If you provide some sample data, we can show how.

Comment: Hello, Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, I added some sample data above. Sorry for any formatting, I am new to posting here. Thanks.